# Replace text in array of objects, bug in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I have written a function replacing text within, for example, an array of textboxes.

The function:

```
Protected Sub Replace(ByVal c1 As Char, ByVal c2 As Char, ByVal ParamArray fields() As TextBox)

    For Each field As TextBox In fields
        field.Text = field.Text.Replace(c1, c2)
    Next

End Sub
```

Called by these codes (both have the same output):

```
Replace(" ", String.Empty, _
            TextBox1, _
            TextBox2 _
            )


Replace(" ", "", _
            TextBox1, _
            TextBox2 _
            )
```

Input: foo bar

Output: foo

Exptected: foobar

Why does it replace all text after the space instead of just the characters I'm giving it?

Comment: You should use `Option Strict On` to avoid implicit conversions. To make a enclosed quotes char act like a char insted of string use this: `" "c`

Comment: This replaces a space by a space, instead of nothing.

Comment: Minor point: you're using `" "` as the find part of the replace, instead of `c1`.

Comment: What I mean is you should use String for both, and of course, use `c1` inside the method, as @JonEgerton said. The replace method takes two strings or two chars, it doesn't allow mixing, so it implicitly convert one of them

Comment: @SysDragon option strict on doesn't allow a string.empty.
JonEgerton oops, I will change it... code from debugging ;).. thanks

Comment: @SysDragon I'm not able to find a solution to replace a single CHAR by an empty CHAR, since an empty char doesn't seem to exist, like an empty string does. 

I changed the sub to take in strings instead of chars, this works fine...even when replacing only 1 character.

Comment: Sure, that was I was saying: to use only strings. There is no problem with one character long strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to find a solution to replace a single CHAR by an empty CHAR, since an empty char doesn't seem to exist, like an empty string does. I changed the sub to take in strings instead of chars, this works fine...even when replacing only 1 character.

Comment: Yes, that's the correct solution. A variable of type `char` always contains *exactly* one character.